# Laravel: I have some problem posting data with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, apache

Im new to using ajax and I have another post here about my code and they said it was correct.
However Im still facing issues

#### My code:

```
body[circle.id] = {id: currentid-1, x: event.offsetX, y: event.offsetY};

// Ajax 
for(let i = 0;i < body.length;i++){
    $.ajax({                    
        url: 'get.php',     
        type: 'post', 
        data : {
            data: body[i],
          },
        dataType: 'json',                   
    });
}
```

The error:
[Error][1]

[image]

Comment: are you using vue.js?

Comment: I'm not using it dirrectly but laravel using it.

Comment: Use axios instead or promise if you use ajax within a loop. And don't forget to check how you grab data in get.php.

Comment: im new to using ajax so i dont know how to grab data in php so there is my sript https://imgur.com/a/9G1Y6lG the other guy in my POST said that's correct way.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing learn how routing works have  a look in the docs

Comment: You need either to pass csrf token with post request either to exclude that URI from verifying token field. Check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf).

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment.

From the title I guess you are using Laravel.

I see you are hitting the file directly, but looks like you are showing only half the setup. In case Laravel.
What is the route setup?
And if the setup is like `Route::get` try `Route::any`.
How are you debugging the issue? Do you have any logs?
Can you check the logs of "web server"?
Either `artisan serve` or `php -S` should give at least some hints what your ajax is hitting.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error image you have posted, The error says that the method only accepts the GET request but you are trying to make POST request in your AJAX method, Change your request type to GET like this,

```
$.ajax({                    
  url: 'get.php',     
  type: 'get', 
  data : {
    data: body[i],
  },
  dataType: 'json',                   
});
```

Comment: I need POST request this is my get.php i know the name is tricky..https://imgur.com/a/9G1Y6lG

Comment: Try to change $_POST to $_GET  and see if you are getting what you want

Comment: Still the same problem method not Allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.The problem was in url and routes